# How can I access the collection of objects associated not just with one other object, but a collection of other objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have two models, Observation and Score, where scores belong to an observation and an observation has many scores.

I can use Observation.first.scores to retrieve a collection of the scores belonging the first observation.

What I'd like to be able to do is call .scores on an arbitrary collection of observations, something like @observations.scores, and get a collection of all the scores associated with all of those observations.

I suppose I could use something like this...
    all_scores = Array.new
    @observations.each do |observation|
      observation.scores.each do |score|
        all_scores.push score
      end
    end

But th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use use `Array#map`:

```
@observations = Observation.all(:include => :scores)
# => [#<Observation>, #<Observation>...]

@all_scores = @observations.map { |o| o.scores } 
# => [[#<Score>, #<Score>], [#<Score>, #<Score>, #<Score>]...]
```

This will give you an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
Score.find(:all, :conditions => ["observation_id in (?)", @observations.collect(&:id)])
```

That would find all scores with an observation in the array of `@observations`.